# Rails - an authentication solution that is not email-centered?(SMS-centered instead)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

It seems that various popular authentication gems including `devise` are heavily built around email. However in some developing countries, a lot of users don't use emails at all and prefer to do the verification by SMS verification codes. It seems to be possible in `devise` to allow users to sign in using something other than email address. However is it possible for the user to recover his/her password by cellphone as well?(i.e. just sending the new password to his/her phone by a SMS service).

Also, it is not clear to me from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address whether I can ditch email field in the sign up form altogether, or just make it *not mandatory*, but still there?

If the above cannot be achieved, then is there any alternative gem solution available? I see gems like https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic seem to be method-agnostic enough. But I'm not sure whether the better solution would be to just build my own authentication system instead of using any gem. I see on RailsGuide that it's preferable to use a gem to do authentication but I'm not exactly sure why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're certain you want to use SMSes for login, I recommend you ditch devise and roll out your own authentication method.

However there are a few things to consider:

1. The deliverability of SMS is lower than emails. There are
   countries with strict no automated SMS policies (e.g. India) and
   countries where SMSes don't work at all (e.g. Myanmar)
2. To alleviate the above problem, implement fallback to voice (take a
   look at Nexmo's [text to speech](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/voice-api/text-to-speech) API)
3. Keep in mind [country specific restrictions](https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/sections/200622473-Country-Specific-Features-and-Restrictions)
4. If you send out a lot of SMSes, spread the load across multiple numbers
5. For safe storage of passwords
   use has_secure_password

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Actually this project targets Chinese market and will probably remain so in the foreseeable future. In China it's almost the norm to do SMS instead of email, and such services abound. Though thanks for broadening my perspective and I'm sure such info will be of use to many others.

Comment: One doubt though, on guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#user-management the RoR Guides says "Almost every web application has to deal with authorization and authentication. Instead of rolling your own, it is advisable to use common plug-ins. But keep them up-to-date, too. A few additional precautions can make your application even more secure." Is there a specific reason for it? Or does it take significantly longer time for myself to implement my secure solution? I assume `has_secure_password` combined with some normal practices such as described in Hartl's book will prevent most dangers?

Comment: Well I guess the guides were written pretty long ago, at which time I'm not even sure `has_secure_password` was available. Now the security of user-defined authentication should be much better. I'll just go with it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you implement your own authentication logic if you are not comfortable with overriding `devise` way of using emails for authentication. For understanding how a simple authentication is done please look at this [book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users) by Micheal Hartl. Replace confirmation by email with confirmation by sms one time password or something of that sort using an API like Twilio.

Comment: I've read the book and I guess indeed it's better to write my own in this occasion. Just one doubt though, on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#user-management the RoR Guides says "Almost every web application has to deal with authorization and authentication. Instead of rolling your own, it is advisable to use common plug-ins. But keep them up-to-date, too. A few additional precautions can make your application even more secure." Is there a specific reason for it? Or does it take significantly longer time for myself to implement my secure solution?

Comment: Well I guess the guides were written pretty long ago, at which time I'm not even sure `has_secure_password` was available. Now the security of user-defined authentication should be much better. I'll just go with it.